# Register an AWS GIT code push event in Exact Online ERP

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-codecommit, exact-online, invantive-sql

When a developer checks in code through a GIT push to AWS codecommit, I want to register an event in our ERP package Exact Online. This allows a project manager to review from within the ERP package the commits.

AWS Codecommit only supports triggers through SNS and Lambda; there is no hookup for batch files or so. I've been playing around with AWS Lambda and managed to post an event from AWS Codecommit to Slack, but to Exact Online it seems harder.

How can I post the GIT event of code commit to a business object in Exact Online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use a combination of AWS Lambda and Invantive Data Access Point, using a script such as:

```
console.log('Loading function codecommit2slack.');

const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const codecommit = new aws.CodeCommit({ apiVersion: '2015-04-13', region: 'eu-west-1' });
const querystring = require('querystring');

const https = require('https');
const url = require('url');
//
// To get the slack hook url, go into slack admin and create a new "Incoming Webhook" integration.
//
const slack_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/SECRET/STUFF';
const slack_req_opts = url.parse(slack_url);
slack_req_opts.method = 'POST';
slack_req_opts.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

exports.handler = function(event, context) 
{
  console.log('Run codecommit2slack.');
  (event.Records || []).forEach(function (rec) 
  {
    var details = rec.codecommit.references[0];
    var commitId = details.commit;
    var ref = details.ref;
    var repository = rec.eventSourceARN.split(":")[5];

    console.log("Repo " + repository + ", commit ID " + commitId + " on " + ref);

    var params = 
    {   commitId: commitId
    ,   repositoryName: repository
    };

    codecommit.getCommit
    (   params
    ,   function(err, data) 
        {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     
            {
                var commitMessage = data.commit.message;
                var authorName = data.commit.author.name;
                var committerName = data.commit.committer.name;

                console.log(commitMessage);

                var postData = querystring.stringify
                (
                    {   'connection': 'PUBLIC\\Exact Online (nl)'
                    ,   'format': 'Xml'
                    ,   'query': "insert into events(description, enddate, notes, startdate, status) values ('" + repository + ": " + commitMessage.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/gmi, "") + "', sysdate, '" + committerName + " / " + commitId + "', sysdate, 50)"
                    }
                )
                ;

                var daphttpoptions =
                {   host: "data-access-point.com"
                ,   port: 443
                ,   path: '/eol/stable/dap/Results'
                ,   auth: 'EXACT-ONLINE-USER' + ":" + 'EXACT-ONLINE-PASSWORD'
                ,   method: 'POST'
                ,   headers:
                    {   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    ,   'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
                    }
                }

                var dapreq = https.request
                ( daphttpoptions
                , function (res) 
                    {
                        if (res.statusCode === 200) 
                        {
                            console.log('posted to DAP');
                            context.succeed('posted to DAP');
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            console.log('post to DAP failed with status code: ' + res.statusCode);
                            context.fail('status code: ' + res.statusCode);
                        }
                    }
                );

                dapreq.on
                ( 'error'
                , function(e) 
                    {
                        console.log('problem with DAP request: ' + e.message);
                        context.fail(e.message);
                    }
                );

                //
                // Send to Data Access Point.
                //
                dapreq.write(postData);

                dapreq.end();

                var req = https.request
                ( slack_req_opts
                , function (res) 
                    {
                        if (res.statusCode === 200) 
                        {
                            console.log('posted to slack');
                            context.succeed('posted to slack');
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            console.log('post to slack failed with status code: ' + res.statusCode);
                            context.fail('status code: ' + res.statusCode);
                        }
                    }
                );

                req.on
                ( 'error'
                , function(e) 
                    {
                        console.log('problem with Slack request: ' + e.message);
                        context.fail(e.message);
                    }
                );

                //
                // Send to development-audit channel.
                //
                req.write(JSON.stringify({username: committerName, as_user: true, text: commitMessage + " on " + repository + " (ID: " + commitId + ", ref " + ref + ")", channel: '#development-audit'}));

                req.end();
            }
        }
    );

  });
};

console.log('Finished loading function codecommit2slack.');
```

This script also includes a post to Slack. First version of code based upon https://gist.github.com/vgeshel/1dba698aed9e8b39a464, thx.

The result in Exact Online will look something like this, but ofcourse you can also use it to create for instance an article or a Serial Number for each new commit or tag:

[image: GIT commits in Exact Online as events]